# smack 4.2 . app always crashing if i build the connection

Tags: android, crash, xmpp, smack

I alrdy read tons of resolutions here in stack but i cant resolve this problem.

1. I give my App Internet premissions
2. i use asynctask
3. my problem is the same. My app is always crashing if i start to build

I tried to do it with try catch . i also tried to do it with the expected thrown but nothing helps. I hope for an smack specialist who can help me out of this hell. Without the Builder the App is running fine without problems

MainActivity.class

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        connectXmpp con= new connectXmpp();
        con.execute();
    }
}
```

connectXmpp.class

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;


import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration;

/**
 * Created by saddam on 08.07.2017.
 */

public class connectXmpp extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,Void>{
    public static XMPPTCPConnection connection;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
                .builder();
        config.setUsernameAndPassword("username","pw");
        config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        config.setHost("dismail.de");
        config.setPort(5222);
        config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
        XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }



}
```

Comment: I recommend to also post the exception and the stacktrace, otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

okay seems like smack 4.2 has a bug. My problem resolve with using this dependencies:

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-core:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-experimental:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-minidns:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-sasl-provided:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.1'
   compile 'org.jxmpp:jxmpp-core:0.4.2-beta1'
   compile 'org.jxmpp:jxmpp-util-cache:0.4.2-beta1'
   compile 'de.measite.minidns:minidns:0.1.1'
```